# Modifying A Custom Active Directory Attribute With PowerShell Error

Tags: powershell, custom-attributes

I am writing a script that contains this code:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity johndoe | Set-ADUser -Replace @{customattribute = 'yes'}
```

...and I am getting this error:

```
Set-ADUser : An attempt was made to modify an object to include an 
attribute that is not legal for its class
At line:1 char:61
+ Get-ADUser -Identity johndoe | Set-ADUser -Replace...
+                                                             
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=John 
Doe,DC=test,DC=local:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ActiveDirectoryServer:8317,
Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

If I do a Get-ADuser instead, I am able to see the custom attribute and the value assigned to it. It is just when I try modifying it with set-ADuser that I get the error.

```
Get-ADUser johndoe -Properties customattribute | ft name,customattribute
name          customattribute
----          ---------------
John Doe      No
```

I've done research and a lot of troubleshooting, but have not been able to solve the problem.  Does anyone have any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: Has this environment been restored from backup at some point? The error you're getting indicates a schema inconsistency (the kind of thing you'd definitely want to open a Microsoft support case for)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  I do not believe that this environment has been restored from backup.  It is a VM that I test my scripts on before I use them on the actual network.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend checking if the Powershell attributes are defunct to troubleshoot if this could stem from schema issues.

The following Powershell command should give you a list of attributes on your ADObjects that are defucted. Check and see if your custom attribute is on this list:

```
$SchemaPath = (Get-ADRootDSE).SchemanamingContext
$DefunctAttributes = Get-ADObject -Filter {Isdefunct -eq $True} -Properties IsDefunct -SearchBase $SchemaPath | Select Name
```

If this is the case I would do as @Mathias R. Jessen suggest and open an MS ticket.

**Edit**
It is odd that it doesn't show up on the list. Have you checked that the attribute is actually part of the schema?

Running this command will show all schema attributes with a name containing "custom":

```
$SchemaPath = (Get-ADRootDSE).SchemanamingContext
Get-ADObject -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $SchemaPath |select Name | Where-Object {$_.name -match "custom"}
```

Does your custom attribute show up on this list?
If now it is missing from the schema somehow.

If it is, I am guessing some sort of corruption is going on and I would raise a ticket with Microsoft regardless.

Comment: I tried your code and my custom attribute did not show up on the list.

Comment: Do you know what datatype your  customproperty has?
You should be able to see this with:
Get-ADUser johndoe -Properties customattribute | Get-Member

Look for your attribute by name.
Then under the definition it should say "string" if it is a text value.

Comment: it says "System.String customattribute {get;set;} " under Definition.

Comment: Added something to try in the answer.

Comment: The attribute is listed in the schema.  I'll try the ticket and see what Microsoft says.  Thank you for the help!